# When is set BlobItemProperties.ContentLength

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I tried understand when is BlobItemProperties.ContentLength set. When I am working with it I see it is set after blob is uploaded but I dont see any information to this in documentation.

BlobItemProperties.ContentLength I am geting by BlobContainerClient.GetPropertiesAsync()

Is there some documentaion or any information when is BlobItemProperties.ContentLength set?

Thanks

Information about BlobItemProperties.ContentLength

Comment: Why are you trying to get size of a blob using `BlobContainerClient.GetPropertiesAsync()`? Shouldn't you be using `BlobClient.GetPropertiesAsync()`?

Comment: Hi @Gaurav Mantri, thanks for notice I have mistake in my question, I am calling BlobClient.GetPropertiesAsync() as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Packages that use `BlobItemProperties` is `com.azure.storage.blob.models`.

`contentLength property` : The number of bytes present in the response body of blob  file.

**you can set and get the content length using the method of blobItemProperties**

For more information would suggest you refer this [**document**](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.4.0/com/azure/storage/blob/models/class-use/BlobItemProperties.html).